# Qt Create a scene with a grid of individual rectangles

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I want to create a grid of 22x22 individual rectangles. I will be filling each rectangle with a colour based on a predefined colour scale.

At the moment my header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

#define GRIDDIM 22

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsRectItem *rec[GRIDDIM*GRIDDIM];




protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

So I have declared 22x22 individual rectangle objects in the rec[] array.

My .cpp file looks like this:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QGraphicsView>


Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    //rec = new QGraphicsRectItem;
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);


    QBrush redBrush(Qt::red);
    QBrush blueBrush(Qt::blue);
    QPen blackPen(Qt::black);
    QPen bluePen(Qt::blue);
    blackPen.setWidth(0);
    bluePen.setWidth(0);

    int height = 15;
    int width = 15;
    int xpos = 0;
    int ypos = 0;


    for (int i=0;i<GRIDDIM;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<GRIDDIM;j++){
        scene->addRect(i*(width),j*(height),width,height,blackPen);
        }
    }
```

But this is just assigning the generic rect object by using addrect.

Is it possible to implement my rec[] array into the scene so that I can then say for example set rec[10] blue?

Using:

```
QGraphicsRectItem *rec = new QGraphicsRectItem(QRect(xpos,ypos,width,height));
```

Gives back an error:

```
allocation of incomplete type 'QGraphicsRectItem'
forward declaration of 'QGraphicsRectItem'
```

Comment: `#include <QGraphicsRectItem>` is missing.

Comment: Note that QGraphicsScene::addRect returns a pointer to the rect which was added: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addRect